# gTTS /python/ - can you text message the .mp3 file in your script?

Tags: python-3.x, twilio, pyttsx

twilio api says it only handles mp4 for audio. Anyone have a solution to save python text to speach as .mp3 or .mp4 and text said audio file  or a call  and the mp3 audio plays.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Twilio does support mp3 files for audio, as well as wav, aiff, gsm and ulaw](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play#nouns).

It looks as though that's exactly what gTTS does for you. The example in the documentation is:

```
>>> from gtts import gTTS
>>> tts = gTTS('hello')
>>> tts.save('hello.mp3')
```

Alternatively, you could just use Twilio's text to speech as part of your call, with [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say). If you are not satisfied with the basic voices [you can now use voices from AWS Polly in Twilio Voice](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/08/introducing-50-additional-text-to-speech-voices-with-amazon-polly-integration.html).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: @ phinash - thank you your for your input, essentially I want to save a variable that contains text as an mp3, and then text said mp3 using twillio. I have updated your comment to include my code attempt

Comment: It's better to update your question rather than my answer, so that we don't have a conversation through edits.

Comment: As for the code, you're trying to send the mp3 file as the body of a text message, which is not going to work. Instead you should look into making calls and [responding with TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml), using [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play) to play mp3 files.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. So there is no way to just text message an mp3 file using python?

Comment: You can send media messages as long as you delivering to a number in the US or Canada. You'd need to include the file as the `mediaUrl` option in the request. Read [these docs for more information](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages?code-sample=code-send-an-mms-message&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=6.x).